# change a certain string in filename (windows batch loop, wildcard)

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

I have a `ogr2ogr` command and I am mixing the command with windows shell command

I have to loop through certain extensions only, which is `*.shp`. And, the command below is where I started

```
for %f in (*.shp) do (ogr2ogr .....
```

but now I have to loop through files with this kind of name.

```
road_node_1.shp
road_node_2.shp
...
road_node_9.shp
```

I played around with many types of wildcard such as

```
for %f in (road_node_*) do (ogr2ogr .....
```

then it loops through all the files that are related to the `*.shp` and the file name (without the extension) is same

```
road_node_1.shx
road_node_1.dbf
road_node_1.cpg
road_node_1.prj..
```

so It does go though unnecessary files, which takes more time to do process

I tried the command below and doesn't work either

```
for %f in (road_node_*.shp) do (ogr2ogr .....
```

I wonder if there is a way to loop through file names like that.

Comment: Of course that this command should work: `for %f in (road_node_*.shp) do (ogr2ogr .....`. I suggest you to use a simple ECHO command for testing: `for %f in (road_node_*.shp) do @echo %f`. PS - Are you aware that the single percent-sign version of the FOR parameters works only in the command-line? If you want to use it in a Batch file, then you should use double percent-signs...

Comment: Deal with batch script is some kind of Low Life, if you understand me.... Besides a cmd fan, do not know the answer for your matters, but learning here too from you, distantly, like an Albatross.

Comment: `Doesn't Work` means `Doesn't do as I expected.` Without knowing what you *expect* to happen and what *actually* happened, we're reduced to guessing. Please `edit` your question to include the extra information. Having said that, is `ogr2ogr` a batch file or another type of executable?

Comment: I have removed the `shell` tag because it has nothing to do with Unix/Linux

Comment: It's either `for %f in (road_node_*.shp) do` or `for %f in (road_node_?.shp) do`; `?` matches one character, `*` matches also more; note that both variants match `road_node_.shp` too...

Answer (score -1):

@Aacini

This is weird...
the command did not work a few hours ago

> for %f in (road_node_*.shp) do

now... this command works like a magic.

I do not know what has been changed though issue solved :(

Comment: Did you go from trying the command in a script to trying it on the command line? `%f` is for the command prompt, `%%f` is for scripts.